# create nested dictionary/json with condition from specific rows pandas dataframe [Tricky]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
   Raw Dataframe loaded and from pdf Example PAGE 1:
Index     0        1         2            3           4            5
0         NaN      Object    1            NaN         NaN         NaN        
1         NaN      ID        Name         Location    Time        ZIP
2          1       009        A           Br          Two         2422
3          2       008        B           Zw          Six         1222
4          3       004        C           Kb          Four        4444
5         NaN      Object     2
6          4       001        W           Bx          Seven        1561
7          5       002        W           Bz          Five         1767
```

```
   Raw Dataframe loaded and from pdf PAGE 2:
Index     0        1         2            3           4            5
9         NaN      Object    2            NaN         NaN         NaN        
10        NaN      ID        Name         Location    Time         ZIP
11          6       009        A           Br          Two         2422
12          7       008        B           Zw          Six         1222
13          8       004        C           Kb          Four        4444
14         NaN      Object     3
15         NaN      ID        Name         Location    Time        ZIP
16          9       001       S          Bx          Seven       1561
17          10      002       S           Bz          Five        1767
```

```
   Raw Dataframe loaded and from pdf PAGE 3:
Index      0        1         2            3           4            5
18         NaN      Object    4            NaN         NaN         NaN        
19         NaN      ID        Name         Location    Time        ZIP
20         11       009        A           Br          Two         2422
21         12       008        B           Zw          Six         1222
22         13       004        C           Kb          Four        4444
23         NaN      Object     5
24         NaN      ID        Name         Location    Time         ZIP
25         14       001        S           Bx          Seven        1561
26         15       002        S           Bz          Five         1767
```

Might seem too complex but there are two important things that we look for:

1. ** Object ** *(column:1)* + it's corresponding number **[1,2,3,4,5]** *(column:2)*
2. There are so called column names or **headers** in some of the rows as you can see (Index: **1**,**6**,**10**,**15**,**19**,**24**  **ID**,**Name**,**Location**,**Time**,**Zip**

Caveats:
sometimes Object appears in a row, after each other without "headers" (ID,Name,Location,Time,Zip)

Idea:

- create a dictionary(nested) that looks something like this:
- ideally by iterating through each row iloc or loc with pandas library
- the point is that everytime keys 'Object{}'.format(its num) is encountered/created it appends its values to it thatis underneath always until next Object is encountered and so on (with headers or even without)
- Important: as long as we know what belongs to what (key: Object# : key1: ... key2: ... key3: ..

```
{Object1: {"Id:"009,008..", "Name:"A,B,C","Location:"Br,Zw,Kb","Time:" Two,Six,Four","Zip:"2422,1222,4444",
{Object2: {"Id:"001,002","Name:"W,W","Location:"Bx,Bz","Time:" Seven,Five","Zip:"1561",
{Object3: {"Id:"...." ","Name:"....","Location:"....","Time:"....","Zip:" ....",
{Object4: {"Id:" .... ","Name:" ....","Location:" ....","Time:" ....","Zip:" ....",
{Object5: {"Id:" .... ","Name:"....","Location:" ....","Time:" ....","Zip:" ...."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I took is to combine each of them into a data frame. Then add a column of object names to fill in the holes. Group the resulting data frames and join them together with commas. And finally, convert the frames into a dictionary with `to_dict()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Index     0        1         2            3           4            5
0         NaN      Object    1            NaN         NaN         NaN        
1         NaN      ID        Name         Location    Time        ZIP
2          1       009        A           Br          Two         2422
3          2       008        B           Zw          Six         1222
4          3       004        C           Kb          Four        4444
5         NaN      Object     2
6          4       001        W           Bx          Seven        1561
7          5       002        W           Bz          Five         1767
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

data2 = '''
Index     0        1         2            3           4            5
9         NaN      Object    2            NaN         NaN         NaN        
10        NaN      ID        Name         Location    Time         ZIP
11          6       009        A           Br          Two         2422
12          7       008        B           Zw          Six         1222
13          8       004        C           Kb          Four        4444
14         NaN      Object     3
15         NaN      ID        Name         Location    Time        ZIP
16          9       001       S          Bx          Seven       1561
17          10      002       S           Bz          Five        1767
'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data2), delim_whitespace=True)

data3 = '''
Index      0        1         2            3           4            5
18         NaN      Object    4            NaN         NaN         NaN        
19         NaN      ID        Name         Location    Time        ZIP
20         11       009        A           Br          Two         2422
21         12       008        B           Zw          Six         1222
22         13       004        C           Kb          Four        4444
23         NaN      Object     5
24         NaN      ID        Name         Location    Time         ZIP
25         14       001        S           Bx          Seven        1561
26         15       002        S           Bz          Five         1767
'''
df3 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data3), delim_whitespace=True)

tmp = pd.concat([df,df2,df3], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
for idx,row in tmp.iterrows():
    if row[2] == 'Object':
        tmp.loc[idx, 'object_name'] = row[2]+str(int(row[3]))
    else:
        pass
tmp['object_name'].fillna(method='Ffill', inplace=True)
tmp.dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace=True)
tmp.set_index('object_name', inplace=True)
tmp.drop(columns=['Index','1'], inplace=True, axis=1)
tmp.columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Location', 'Time', 'Zip']
tmp['ID'] = tmp['ID'].astype(str)
tmp['Zip'] = tmp['Zip'].astype(str)
tmp = tmp.groupby('object_name')[['ID','Name','Location','Time','Zip']].agg({'ID':','.join,'Name':','.join,'Location':','.join,'Time':','.join,'Zip':','.join})

tmp.to_dict(orient='index')

{'Object1': {'ID': '1.0,2.0,3.0',
  'Name': 'A,B,C',
  'Location': 'Br,Zw,Kb',
  'Time': 'Two,Six,Four',
  'Zip': '2422,1222,4444'},
 'Object2': {'ID': '4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0',
  'Name': 'W,W,A,B,C',
  'Location': 'Bx,Bz,Br,Zw,Kb',
  'Time': 'Seven,Five,Two,Six,Four',
  'Zip': '1561,1767,2422,1222,4444'},
 'Object3': {'ID': '9.0,10.0',
  'Name': 'S,S',
  'Location': 'Bx,Bz',
  'Time': 'Seven,Five',
  'Zip': '1561,1767'},
 'Object4': {'ID': '11.0,12.0,13.0',
  'Name': 'A,B,C',
  'Location': 'Br,Zw,Kb',
  'Time': 'Two,Six,Four',
  'Zip': '2422,1222,4444'},
 'Object5': {'ID': '14.0,15.0',
  'Name': 'S,S',
  'Location': 'Bx,Bz',
  'Time': 'Seven,Five',
  'Zip': '1561,1767'}}
```

Comment: Basically .fillna does the magic. After that, I can easily just drop all those rows which have no values (NA), which can be seen from column 0. 
Man thank you very much for this approach it helped me definitely! Much appreciation

Comment: By the way, forgot to mention, in some of the rows "Object" comes after each other in a row in that case, fillna 'Ffil' takes the last valid observation. Is there any smart way to tackle such a problem where for instance there's a condition that checks whether Object1 Object2 even Object3 in separate rows beneath each other with the same NA values and frame as seen above and to maybe concatanate them Object1Object2Object3 and then fill the missing values as you suggested as well.

Comment: There are 'bfill' as well as 'ffill' to make up for the loss value. It fills in from the back values. If this doesn't solve the problem, specific sample data will help you to answer the question additionally.